# Преобразование примитивных типов в java нагружает процессор?

Tags: java, преобразование-типов

Собственно интересно как лучше поступать - создавать переменные с byte или с int, если известно что число никогда не будет больше границ byte;

Склоняюсь к мнению что преобразование примитивных типов в любом случае нагружает процессор (да, понятно что это меньше капли), но может я ошибаюсь.

Из минусов это то что потом в коде в нужных местах постоянно придется дописывать (byte).

Приоритет на быстродействие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь есть развёрнутые ответы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst.

Вкратце: используйте `int`. `byte` поле класса всё равно будет храниться в 32-битной ячейке. Но если у вас есть очень большие массивы примитивов, при использовании более коротких типов можно сэкономить память.

Comment: Спасибо, познавательно. Все равно остаются сомнения.